# how to remove blue outline from bootstrap 5 range input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried removing the outline using shadow none, but its not working is there another solution

[image: range input]

Html code

```
<label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Example range</label>
<input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
```

Css code

```
input[type="range"]{
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: could you edit the post and add a code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer by looking at file `_custom-forms.scss` from bootstraps src.

This is how you do a live snippet:

```css
input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Example range</label>
<input type="range" tabindex="-1" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
```